# running rinkeby network on mist

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I am receiving the attached error message while running on Mist.  Now I am even have trouble connecting to Mist and receiving Ethereum Node connection.

Please advise.

The image shows the error I receive everytime I try to run Mist wallet now. 
 [image]

Comment: Please try to make your question clearer. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about How to Ask a question on SO.

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.